# Raycasting causing distortions further from screen it gets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js, raycasting

I have been working on a very rudimentary raycaster, and i have a fisheye type distortion.
heres the code that i have:

```
 var a = new part(player.x,player.y,rr(player.angle-22.5+(2.25*i))[0]/accuracy,rr(player.angle-22.5+(2.25*i))[1]/accuracy);
 var c = 0, m, n;
 while (!level[Math.round(a.x)][Math.round(a.y)]) {
   a.x += a.Dx;
   a.y += a.Dy;
   c++;
 }
 n=dist(a.x,a.y,player.x,player.y);
 m=1/n*400;
 cols[i].height = Math.round(m);
 cols[i].shapeColor=rgb(n*20+10,n*20+10,n*20+10);
```

the function `rr()` just returns the rise/run of the angle inputted. (a degree input)

part is short for particle and i have x, y, delta x (Dx) and deta y (Dy)

a wall is marked by a 1 on the array i have, a floor is marked as  a 0.

```
var level = [
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1],
  [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1],
  [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],
  [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
  [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,0,1,1],
  [1,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,1],
];
```

[image]

I want the height of the column to be determined from the distance, and i currently have it as 1/distance, but that causes a curved wall the further it gets away from the origin of the cast. that's what i want to fix.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173966/raycasting-engine-rendering-creating-slight-distortion-increasing-towards-edges

Comment: Remember to still _ask a question_: you've described what you have, but not what you want to actually do, or how what your code does doesn't match what you had hoped for, and most importantly: you've not asked for help with anything in your post. Also, on a coding for p5 note, p5 has `round()` (no need for the `Math` namespace), and it's still JS so if `part` is a class, capitalise it to `Part`. Things starting with lowercase are variables or functions.

Comment: i edited the question as said what i want to fix.